# Как в input'е с атрибутом list изменить иконку стрелки?

Tags: html, css, html5, input

Как в `input`-е с атрибутом `list` изменить иконку стрелки и сделать ее видимой постоянно? По дефолту она становится видимой только по наведению мышкой.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

```css
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input list="name">

<datalist id="name">
    <option value="name1">
     <option value="name2">
    <option value="name3">
    <option value="name4">
</datalist>
```

**Вариант 2**

```css
.b-input {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.b-input:before,
.b-input:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.b-input:after {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #C0C0C0;
  transition: .3s;
}
.b-input:before {
  top: 50%;
  right: 5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 5px 0 5px;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
  z-index: 1;
}
.b-input:hover:before {
  border-top-color: #fff;
}
.b-input:hover:after {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-input">
  <input list="name">
</div>

<datalist id="name">
  <option value="name1">
  <option value="name2">
  <option value="name3">
  <option value="name4">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо) А если нужно свою иконку с glyphicons или font-awesome вместо стандартной, как быть?

Comment: пример с иконкой - https://jsfiddle.net/1w40r0n6/1/